# Plural form of tardy

Tags: plural-forms

What is the plural form use of "tardy" such as: number of tardy arrivals to school, work, etc.? Word spell check does not have any suggested words in this instance.

Comment: In your example you are using *tardy* as an adjective. Back when I was in school, "tardies" referred to multiple events of being late for school. Ex: "You have three *tardies* this month, so you will have to go see the counselor." But it doesn't seem to be an official word.

Answer (score 2):

tardy
***noun***

> an occasion when you are late for a class, or a record that a teacher keeps of this

[MacMillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/tardy_2)

The plural is *tardies*.

See also [Wiktionary](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/tardy):

tardy ‎(plural tardies)

(US) A piece of paper given to students who are late to class.
*The teacher gave her a tardy because she did not come into the classroom until after the bell.*

---

Before turning to the dictionary I had posted the following:

As to saying that *tardy* is an adjective, well it is also used as a noun. Someone can have one absence and one tardy this week. Or someone could have two or more *tardies*.

We can indeed convert adjectives to nouns by using only the first part  of an "adjective-noun"  combination. Consider *smiley face*. That became *[smiley](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/smiley)*. Oh, my gosh  this girl likes to use smileys in her texts.

If a word is used as a noun, it's a noun.

Answer (score 1):

Tardy is an adjective. There is no plural.

Your sentence ("number of tardy arrivals to school") is correct.

Comment: Well, you could use it as a noun and say "You're all a bunch of tardys!" That has a nice ring to it. :)

Comment: *Tardy* is also used as a noun, in American English.

Answer (score 1):

While tardy as an adjective can't be made plural, you can use [tardiness](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/tardiness) to talk about more than once instance of being late.

> Your tardiness is becoming a problem. Please show up to meetings on time.

In the US, tardy is most commonly associated with grade school students. There are some instances of turning "tardy" into a noun, such as:

> At Casey County Middle School in rural Liberty, Kentucky, Principal
>   Terry Price says, “We had as many as 40 tardies per class period in
>   the morning." [*Source*](http://www.safeandcivilschools.com/research/articles/tamingtardies.pdf)

In this sense, I think the principal was shortening 'tardy students' to 'tardies' but it could also be 'tardy slips', or notices that a student was late to class. In contexts other than talking about students, some explanation of tardies might be necessary, because it is not standard English. I would be reluctant to talk about a group of adult coworkers as tardies - it seems a little bit disrespectful to talk about them like they are children.